# Increase efficiency - parse integers from string C++

Tags: c++, string, parsing, c++11, int

I have a string:

> 12:56:72

I need to get the 3 numbers (*12*, *56*, and *72*) individually.

I am doing:

```
int i=0,j=0,k=0,n, p[3]; // p[i] stores each ith value
char x[], b[];
x="12:34:56";
n=strlen(x);
while(i<strlen){
        b[k]=x[i];
        ++i;
        ++k;
        if(x[i==]':'){
            p[j]=int(b);
            ++j;
            ++i;
            k=0;
            char temp[] = b;
            b=new char[];
            delete temp;
            }
        }
```

Can this be done more efficiently?

Comment: How are you getting the string?  If it is coming from a input stream you can read it directly into the integers.

Comment: I'm getting it from an input stream using fstream. How do I get the integers directly?

Comment: Will the numbers always be two digits or can they be one digit in length?

Comment: They could be one digit in length.

Comment: There are so many errors in the code that doing it more efficiently is meaningless. Post code that compiles and runs.

Comment: @PeteBecker I typed out a snippet from my memory, I'll keep it in mind next time when I post something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be "more efficient", you will have to profile.

Here is another solution:

```
const std::string test_data("01:23:45");
unsigned int hours;
unsigned int minutes;
unsigned int seconds;
char separator;
std::istringstream input(test_data);
// Here's the parsing part
input >> hours >> separator >> minutes >> separator >> seconds;
```

Whether this is "more efficient" or not, must be measured.
It looks simpler and safer.

**Edit 1:  Method 2**
Processors don't like loops or branches, so we can try to minimize.
This optimization assumes perfect input as a string.

```
static const char test_data[] = "01:23:45";
unsigned int hours;
unsigned int minutes;
unsigned int seconds;
char c;
unsigned int index = 0;
hours = test_data[index++] - '0';
if (test_data[index] != ':')
{
  hours = hours * 10 + test_data[index++] - '0';
}
++index; // Skip ':'
minutes = test_data[index++] - '0';
if (test_data[index] != ':')
{
  minutes = minutes * 10 + test_data[index++] - '0';
}
++index; // Skip ':'
seconds = test_data[index++] - '0';
if (test_data[index] != ':')
{
  seconds = seconds * 10 + test_data[index++] - '0';
}
```

For highest optimizations, you have to make some assumptions.  Another assumption is that the character encoding is UTF8 or ASCII, e.g. '1' - '0' == 1.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are reading the data in from a file stream you can use the `operator >>` of that stream to your advantage.  When it inputs data into a `int` it will keep reading the file until it hits a character that would be invalid for an `int`.  This meas it will read the integer part and leave the colon in the file. Because of this behavior we can use

```
ifstream fin("filename.ext");
int a, b, c;
char colon;
while(fin >> a >> colon >> b >> colon >> c)
{
    // do stuff with a, b and c
}
```

And this will read file line by line as long as the file has lines in the format of `12:56:72`.

Comment: This worked, thank you.

I tried Thomas's method before I saw (and tried) this.
Because of my rep, it isn't showing my up-vote.

Comment: @AgentWeirdo No problem. Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a clock, but still, you can scan strings with sscanf:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   char myclock[] = "10:11:12";
   int hours, minutes, seconds;
   sscanf(myclock, "%d:%d:%d", &hours, &minutes, &seconds);
   cout << hours << endl;
   cout << minutes << endl;
   cout << seconds << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using C++ functions.

```
#include <string>
#include  <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    size_t i=0,j=0,k=0, p[3]; // p[i] stores each ith value
    string x("12:34:56");
    for (j=0; j<3; j++) {
        p[j] = stoi(x.substr(k), &i);
        k += i+1;
    }

    for (j =0; j < 3; j++)
        cout << p[j] << endl;
}
```